# JSF Bean Validation Constraints don't have any effect

Tags: java, jsf, bean-validation

I couldn't get Java Bean Validation (JSR-303) working. It doesn't give any error and processes the action method. I put one character to "name" inputText, it accepts and process() method gets executed (Size annotation doesn't apply).

When I put one character I expect the My.Process() method to not to be executed, am I not right?
Is there any configuration I overlook to get validation working?

In WEB-INF/lib dir of my project I have **validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar**, **hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar**.
App Server: **Tomcat 7.0.25** (inside Tomcat's Lib folder I have **myfaces-api-2.1.5.jar** and **myfaces-impl-2.1.5.jar**).
IDE: Eclipse Helios SR2

I get the message "INFO: MyFaces Bean Validation support disabled" from console, but I have the jars as I specified.

**Bean**

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@ManagedBean(name="my")
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
  @Size(min=3, message="ERROR")
  private String name;

  public String process() {...}

  ...getters, setters, etc...
}
```

**JSF form**

```
<h:form>
    <h:messages />
    <h:inputText value="#{my.name}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{my.process}" />
</h:form>
```

I also tried:
@NotEmpty, @NotBlank,
@org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length(min=3, message="ERROR")
but they don't work too.

Comment: Your code works in my environment (GF 3.1.1, Mojarra 2.1.3). I have no additional validation apis other than the one with Glassfish (Java EE6 bean-validation.jar).

Comment: Well I actually simplified my code before writing here but this exact simplified version doesn't work for me too on my environment that I specified above. I'm really tired of trying to find the problem. It doesn't make any sense? I read dozens of web pages about jsf bean validation and according to all of them it should work...

Comment: I get the message below at console, I'm trying to find why it says this. I have the jars I specified above in place.
"INFO: MyFaces Bean Validation support disabled"

Comment: Haha it worked! I downloaded "bean-validator.jar" from some place and put it into my classpath and now bean validation enabled, also it works :) Thank you for pointing out that jar file Matt! But it is really weird that there's no information related bean validation to that jar. I can't even find a proper information about which project that jar belongs to.

Comment: I investigated bean-validator.jar and it looks like a combination of validation-api.jar and hibernate-validator-4.0.2-GA.jar
So I removed it and the validation now still works! I'm sometimes afraid of never understanding java totally :)

Comment: I could solve the same problem using maven by adding `<dependency><groupId>javax.validation</groupId><artifactId>validation-api</artifactId></dependency>` to my pom.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to write a possible problem.

When I had have this variable

```
private String Name;
```

Validation didn't work because the getter and setters are like this

```
private String getName(){}
```

So I renamed Name to

```
private String name;
```

and it started to validate :)

Probably that was the problem.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074802/bean-validation-not-working-if-name-variable-is-prefixed-with-underscore

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this! FYI, maven coordinates for bean-validator:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>bean-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-JBoss-4.0.2_03</version>
</dependency>
```