# spring boot : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, castor

I have setup a spring boot project and using castor xml dependency to convert a POJO to xml.

```
compile 'org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:1.3.3'
```

facing an issue while calling marshal method for a POJO. I have looked up other related questions on stackoverflow but none of them having a solution for my scenario.

There is toString method which is inside a spring component.

Here is the snippet  :

```
public String toString(Client client) throws MarshalException, org.exolab.castor.xml.ValidationException {
    String xml = null;

    // Create the xml
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    client.marshal(sw);
    xml = sw.toString();

    return xml;
  }
```

And here is the marshal method inside client (auto generated class by castor earlier):

```
public class Client implements java.io.Serializable {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 5203108777533793020L;
      private Object _clientId;
      private String _someOtherField;
      private List<Address> _addresses; // this is also serialized;

       public void marshal(final java.io.Writer out) throws org.exolab.castor.xml.MarshalException,org.exolab.castor.xml.ValidationException{
               Marshaller.marshal(this, out);
        }
```

Here is the stacktrace for the same:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at org.exolab.castor.mapping.loader.FieldHandlerImpl.getValue(FieldHandlerImpl.java:409) ~[castor-xml-1.3.3.jar:${VERSION}${RELEASE}]
at org.exolab.castor.xml.Marshaller.processAttribute(Marshaller.java:2662) ~[castor-xml-1.3.3.jar:${VERSION}${RELEASE}]
at org.exolab.castor.xml.Marshaller.marshal(Marshaller.java:1534) ~[castor-xml-1.3.3.jar:${VERSION}${RELEASE}]
at org.exolab.castor.xml.Marshaller.marshal(Marshaller.java:997) ~[castor-xml-1.3.3.jar:${VERSION}${RELEASE}]
at com.demo.xml.Client.marshal(Client.java:328) ~[classes/:?]
at com.demo.client.Processor.toString(Processor.java:244) ~[classes/:?]
at com.demo.client.Processor$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$efa7e4a2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at com.demo.client.Processor$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$95910882.toString(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
at com.demo.goal.test.SaveDemo.saveDemo(SaveDemo.java:71) ~[classes/:?]
at com.demo.goal.test.DemoService.start(DemoService.java:138) ~[classes/:?]
at com.demo.goal.test.DemoService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9bb23164.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at com.demo.goal.test.DemoService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$785cf808.start(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
at com.demo.rest.v20.goal.DemoController.start(DemoController.java:48) ~[classes/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) [spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at com.demo.commons.security.authentication.jwt.JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:105) [classes/:?]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at com.demo.commons.security.oauth2.OAuth2Authenticator.doFilter(OAuth2Authenticator.java:37) [classes/:?]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) [spring-security-oauth2-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_181]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181]
```

**Strage thing to notice here is the code works as expected when I execute code from Junit test. but when I invoke the webservice from swagger API, I get the error.**

Comment: ...assuming that your getters/setters don't have an underscore (`_`), please "try" the following: `private Object clientId; private String someOtherField; private List<Address> addresses;` (no underscore!) ..and `public void setSomeOtherField(String s) / String getSomeOtherField()`...

Comment: ..my "feeling" is backed by: "In **introspection** mode , Castor XML uses Java **reflection** to establish the binding between the Java classes (and their **properties**) and the XML, following a set of *(default) naming rules*." from [castor-xml-doc](https://castor-data-binding.github.io/castor/reference-guide/reference/xml/xml-framework.html) ..and (e.g.): [Bean validation not working if name variable is prefixed with underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11074802/592355)

Comment: Your best chance to solve this is probably debugging. Place a breakpoint in FileHandlerImpl:409 and inspect the values of the different attributes. The exception is basically telling you that castor tries to invoke a method on an instance that doesn't know this method. Additionally castor might not be the best choice for XML-mapping as it has not been updated for almost 4 years and version 1.3.3 is more than 5 years old. Perhaps Jackson XML binding are better suited and supported: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml

Comment: How's your `com.demo.client.Processor` being created. When I tried your `Client` class both with `swagger` and `curl`, I didn't notice any exception. Here's my response `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<client>
  <_client-id xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:java="http://java.sun.com" least-significant-bits="-8144948592009977823" most-significant-bits="8836034799169390766" xsi:type="java:java.util.UUID"/>
  <_some-other-field>any field</_some-other-field>
  ...
</client>`

Answer (score 0):

Please "try" the following:

#### no underscore!

```
private Object clientId; 
private String someOtherField;
private List<Address> addresses; 
//and "normal" getters/setters ...
public void setClientId(Object cId) { //...
```

---

..my "feeling" is backed by:

> In **introspection** mode , Castor XML uses Java **reflection** to establish the binding between the Java classes (and their **properties**) and the XML, following a set of **(default) naming rules**.

... [from castor-xml-doc](https://castor-data-binding.github.io/castor/reference-guide/reference/xml/xml-framework.html)

The only "defaul naming rules" for "properties" I am aware of are the:

**[Java Bean Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html)**(-> **8.3 Design Patterns for Properties**)

... which might explain your described problem/stacktrace. ..See also (e.g.): [Bean validation not working if name variable is prefixed with underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11074802/592355)

---

Still doesn't explain the *difference* between "test" and "swagger" execution, but to pardon: very few information on this *and* (I am very confident that) the proposed fix won't break "swagger".

We face a problem, when the effort to eliminate (all) underscores is "huge" ... then we *should understand the difference*!